# Where do I extract and install the .txz file of the Shotcut Video editor?

Tags: linux, debian, chrome-book, chrome-os, video-editing

I recently installed Shotcut on my Chromebook via the Linux Virtual Environment (Debian) on the Terminal. While the program works for the most part, it is also asked me to update to the latest version. I downloaded the .txz files from the site but I am not sure where to extract the files. The version of the Shotcut video editor that I have installed is not the latest version.

The .txz file is but I have no idea where to extract the file on Linux. I cannot use the Terminal to update it either as it tells me that I have the latest version. The .txs file is the lastest version and it has all the updated files.  What should I do? Should I reinstall the software? Should I find a .rom or .deb file?

Answer (score 0):

Your .txz files are packed archives, similar to .zip files that you extract using `tar -xJf file.txz`. Typically, such archives contain shell scripts that automatically download an update. if it is extracted you have to execute it.

On Chromebooks, programs are updated automatically. If there is a higher version of a program than the one you have on your Chromebook, you'll need to wait until the update is included in the Chrome OS distribution. Alternatively, you can find a .deb package and install it with sudo apt install your-deb.deb.

Comment: I see. The Linux version of Shotcut that I installed from the Terminal is the "newest" one for that OS. The only way to get the new one is either the Appimage or the archive. Do I have to wait for the update for the one I have? It is the Linux version by the way.